# JavaScript function not called on client click

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer

I have asp button and i want to call a java script function on client click its working on chrome but not in IE. I have searched in many sites but with no answer.

Comment: function ShowConfirm() {
            alert(hdnConfirm);            
            var hdnConfirm = document.getElementById("<%= hdnConfirm.ClientID %>");
            if (hdnConfirm.value == "1") {
                if (!confirm("This Referring Provider is already mapped with a MR. Are you sure to map this Referring Provider with other MR?") == true) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

Comment: please edit your post with the code. No one can read that

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnResMod" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Save" 
                    ValidationGroup="valSumResMod" OnClientClick="javascript:return ShowConfirm();"/>

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question, code in the comments is almost unreadable.

Comment: Yes, you are. Edit your question and use the "code sample" button, then paste your code in there.

Answer (score 0):

In the function ShowConfirm() , hdnConfirm is used before its declaration inside alert.
The code is crashed there and not executed further.
try to use it after declration

Answer (score 0):

Please check your IE browser setting, make sure you have enabled the JavaScript.

To enable/disable the JavaScript in IE 11, you could refer to the following steps:

1. Select the Gear in the upper-right corner of the screen or the "Tools" menu if you have the menu bar enabled, then select "Internet Options".
2. Select the "Security" tab.
3. Select the zone you wish to modify. **"Internet" and "Local Intranet".**
4. Select the "Custom level…" button.
5. Scroll down to the "Scripting" area and select the radio button to "Enable" or "Disable" it "Active scripting". You may also opt for IE11 to "Prompt" you to allow scripts to run.
6. Select "OK", then "OK" again.

After enabling the script, according to your code, I create a sample using the following code, it works well on my IE browser (IE 11):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowConfirm() {
        alert(hdnConfirm);
        var hdnConfirm = document.getElementById("<%= hdnConfirm.ClientID %>");
        if (hdnConfirm.value == "1") {
            if (!confirm("This Referring Provider is already mapped with a MR. Are you sure to map this Referring Provider with other MR?") == true) {
                alert("Hello");
                return false;
            }
        } return true;
    }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="btnResMod" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="valSumResMod" OnClientClick="javascript:return ShowConfirm();" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnConfirm" runat="server" Value="1" />
```

The result like this:

[image]